# How to say "I wish I could do something"

Tags: grammar, potential-form

ok, so once again anime got me thinking too hard about grammar.

Let's take the sentence "I wish I could move" it could (probably) be something like 動けるになりたい。

But I was wondering can we skip the になる part and do something like 動けたい (coming from potential form 動けます)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

動けたい is strange. 動けていたい and 動いていたい and 動けるようになりたいis acceptable.
(動ける+している=動けている している+いたい=していたい 動けている+していたい=動けていたい)

動けていたい can be used like thinking of when you get old,you want your arms to be able to move. I thin jhis word is grammatically correct but not used so much.
動いていたい can be used like you want to to move your arms anytime. Nobody would say that this word is grammatically strange.
動けるようになりたい can be used like you are unable to move now but wanting to move. I don't know the context but this may be the best.